# Does rustc always ignore inline(never) when optimization is used?

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust code:

```rust
#[inline(never)]
fn x() -> i32 {
    21
}

pub fn main() -> i32 {
    x()
}
```

With no optimization (`-C opt-level=0`), the function call is not inlined, even if `#[inline(never)]` is removed.

```
example::x:
        mov     eax, 21
        ret

example::main:
        push    rax
        call    example::x
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

However, any other optimization level will cause the function to be inlined no matter what.

```
example::main:
        mov     eax, 21
        ret
```

I know that the `inline` attribute is only a suggestion to the compiler, but I can't seem to find any examples where using `#[inline(never)]` would actually stop a function from being inlined when it otherwise would be.

Here is the Compiler Explorer result: https://godbolt.org/z/WKfevdW37

Answer (score 5):

If I had to guess, a function without side effects (e.g. you can mark it `const fn` without any errors) is treated as a special optimization separate from inlining. If you give `x` a side effect (e.g. printing something), then `inline(never)` **will** have an effect:

```rs
#[inline(never)]
fn x() -> i32 {
    println!("foo");
    21
}

pub fn main() -> i32 {
    x()
}
```

This doesn't inline in `opt-level=0` or `opt-level=2`, but if you remove the `inline(never)`, then it will inline in `opt-level=2`.